# Need to determine the correct start capacitor for hvac unit

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heater, capacitor

[image]I need to replace the start capacitor in my HVAC unit and I don't see any identifiable markings on it. This unit also has a heat pump. I believe this start cap is for the heater. I found the part numbers on the manufacture website but they 6 different models. How do I determine which one is correct? Here are the pictures of my model and the parts available. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the caps you're asking about on the compressor motor or the fan motor?

Comment: This unit also has a heat pump. I believe this cap is for the heat pump or possibly the compressor motor. I smelled burning when we first turned on the heat this year. I'm assuming it was the start capacitor that caused the smell.

Comment: The burning smell is the hot from the coils possibly the emergency heat since your motor was not starting. Start or run caps depending on the design are there to create a phase shift to help motors get to speed or to stay at speed with less current. Something going up in smoke outside in the outside unit won’t have any smell inside. A heat pump is a simple valve in a air conditioning system that reverses the refrigerant flow changes from moving heat to the outside to moving heat to the inside.

Answer (score 1):

You have a single start cap there not a dual (from the wires I can see)  The resistor is a safety bleed down for the cap.  I would ASSUME that the blower motor uses a run cap and if you look on the upper right of the label on the blower motor it does give a run cap value of 5.5mfd.  Bleed resistors are not normal on run caps.  You may be able to find the value of the needed start cap by looking at the compressor nameplate.  You can use any cap of the correct capacitance and voltage and if it lacks a bleed resistor and the bleed resistor is still good on that cap in the picture you can move it to the new cap.  I'm sorry to tell you but none of your pictures have legible writing when blown up enough to read.

Comment: Where would I locate the compressor name plate? I'll try to upload better pictures

Comment: Only 2 leads it has to be a start or run cap the bleed resistor is more common on higher end units in both locations. The size in uf is normally stamped on the side but with the motor size we could figure it out. Cheap caps like this usually only last 4-5 years it looks like it may have been bad for a while.

Comment: What is strange is if it is a start cap then with that much damage you would think the fan or compressor wouldn't turn on.  So maybe it is a run cap but it is a mystery to me why they would put a resistor on a run cap since they are not needed, when power to the motor is shut off the motor is still turning and that bleeds down the run cap.  It's got to be a start cap.  The compressor nameplate is on the compressor it is the large sealed black box that the pipes go in and out of.  Follow the cooling lines.  Often the plate is inconveniently located.